# Flutter: type 'Event' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i'm using TableCalendar to display event from Firebase. I "successfully" displayed them in calendar, but day's with events colored red with error `type 'Event' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'`. I followed guides on [pub dev page](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar) of package to display events. How can i fix it? I wan't to only display events on calendar without title

My main code:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getEvents();
  }

  getEvents() async {
    var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('events').get();
    List<Event> eventList = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.docs.length; i++) {
      var time = (data.docs[i]['date'] as Timestamp).toDate();
      var title = Event(data.docs[i]['title']);
      map[time] = title;
    }

    print(map);
  }

  List _getEventsForDay(DateTime day) {
    final events = LinkedHashMap(equals: isSameDay, hashCode: getHashCode)
      ..addAll(map);
    return events[day] ?? [];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appbar('title'),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: TableCalendar(
          firstDay: kFirstDay,
          lastDay: kLastDay,
          focusedDay: _focusedDay,
          eventLoader: (day) {
            return _getEventsForDay(day);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

My model file:

```
class Event {
  final String title;

  const Event(this.title);

  @override
  String toString() => title;
}

Map<DateTime, dynamic> map = {};

int getHashCode(DateTime key) {
  return key.day * 1000000 + key.month * 10000 + key.year;
}

final kToday = DateTime.now();
final kFirstDay = DateTime(kToday.year, kToday.month - 1, kToday.day);
final kLastDay = DateTime(kToday.year, kToday.month + 1, kToday.day);
```

Comment: try specifying type in `_getEventsForDay` function like this: `List<Event> _getEventsForDay(DateTime day)`

Comment: Now i got error saying `type 'Event' is not a subtype of type 'List<Event>'`

Comment: yeah bc you are returning `events[day]` which is an event and not a list of events!

Comment: How can i fix that? Could you help me with that?

Comment: i also encounter the issue with firebase & table calendar when migrating to null safety ... could u share full code for my reference pls ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the for loop where you are casting firestore data to the map

```
    for (int i = 0; i < data.docs.length; i++) {
      var time = (data.docs[i]['date'] as Timestamp).toDate();
      var title = Event(data.docs[i]['title']);
      map[time] = title;
    }
```

Accroding to the documentation [table_calender #event](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar#events)

> _getEventsForDay() can be of any implementation. For example, a Map<DateTime, List<T>> can be used:

The map should be a subtype of `Map<DateTime, List<T>>` but you are casting an event instead of the list.

So change your code as below and add title in a `List<Event>`

```
    for (int i = 0; i < data.docs.length; i++) {
      var time = (data.docs[i]['date'] as Timestamp).toDate();
      var title = Event(data.docs[i]['title']);
      map[time] = [title];
    }
```

- To always prevent this problem from happening and code readability specify the type of variables when declaring them

Comment: So... I added [] brackets to title. And changed _getEventsForDay 's type to List<Event>. But in declaration of map i'm having an error `The name 'T' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.`

Comment: `T` represents a type that you are using now, in this case it's an `Event` so declare it like this `Map<DateTime, List<Event>> map`

Comment: I changed T to Event. Now all of my dates in calendar showing an error: Another exception was thrown: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<DateTime, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<DateTime, List<Event>>' of 'function result'

Comment: I fixed it, i just added Future<Map<DateTime, List<Event>>> before getEvent

Comment: Also, do you know how to display multiple event dots under date? I have two event in 11, calendar displaying only one dot

Comment: @IBlackVikingl Sorry I didn't use this plugin yet. Please clarify your question in a new post